# Linq Select Statements - Where Not In

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to write up the LINQ statement that is equivalent to:

```
select e.EmployeeID, EmployeeName = e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName
from Employees e
where e.EmployeeID not in
(
    select EmployeeID from Managers
)
```

I think I'm pretty close with the following:

```
from e in Employees
where e.EmployeeID !=    // This is where I'm lost
(
    from m in Managers select m.EmployeeID
)
select new
{
    e.EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName = e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName
}
```

I'm trying to put this into a Html.DropDownList.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what the proper query notation for this is, but the following expanded syntax will get the job done

```
var result = Employees
  .Where( e => !Managers.Where(m => m.EmployeeId == e.EmployeeId).Any())
  .Select( e => new { EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId, EmployeeName = e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName);
```

Comment: While this surely works it should be noted that depending on how the query gets executed and (not) optimized it *might* have a terrible performance.

Comment: @emaster70, I think the best way to describe it is that it has E*M performance in Big O notation.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Any`:

```
from e in Employees
where !Managers.Any(m => m.EmployeeID == e.EmployeeID)
select new
{
    e.EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName = e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName
}
```

Or, using a left join:

```
from e in Employees
join m in Managers on e.EmployeeID equals m.EmployeeID into managerGroup
from m in managerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
where m == null
select new
{
    e.EmployeeID,
    EmployeeName = e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the result you want with a [fluid implementation of Linq.Except()](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/Fluid_Linq_Except.aspx):

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee { EmployeeID = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" },
        new Employee { EmployeeID = 2, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" },
        new Employee { EmployeeID = 3, FirstName = "Eddie", LastName = "Punchclock" }
    };
List<Employee> managers = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee { EmployeeID = 2, FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" },
    };
var nonManagerEmployees = employees.Except(managers, x => x.EmployeeID)
    .Select(x => new
        {
            x.EmployeeID,
            EmployeeName = x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName
        });

foreach(var entry in nonManagerEmployees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.EmployeeID+" "+entry.EmployeeName);
}
```

output:

```
1 John Smith
3 Eddie Punchclock
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .Contains() method and insert an ! creating a NOT style syntax.

This would be {collection}.Contains(this != to that);

This may be of interest to you too: http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/billwagner/archive/2006/04/10/linq-samples-part-11.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about using the IN statement with LINQ.  With a little elbow grease I'm sure you could modify the technique to do a NOT IN.

http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx