# How to Attain a list of items of items not on another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, except

I want to attain a list of `BeerNames` from a list whose names are not on a second list.

```
var myList=(from f in Beers where ...
              select f.BeerNames).ToList

var storeList(from f in Store where...
                select f).ToList()
```

MyList will have some BeerNames that are not on StoreList. How do I find those BeerNames? I tried `.Except` and `!Contains` but I realize I'm doing something wrong, and missing some key bit of knowledge.
thanks

If I change

```
var storeList(from f in Store where...
                select f).ToList()
```

to

```
var storeList(from f in Store where...
                select f.BeerNames).ToList()
```

then I can use except such as `List1.Except(List2)`. I wasn't sure if there was a better way. Sorry folks if this isn't clear...I'm trying:)

Comment: Can you post the details of your entity? Did you look at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640259/linq-select-where-object-does-not-contain-items-from-list OR THIS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015081/linq-select-statements-where-not-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list1 = new String[] {"ABC1","ABC2", "ABC3", "ABC4"} ;
var list2 = new String[] {"ABC3","ABC4", "ABC5", "ABC6"} ;
var list3 = list1.Except(list2); // list3 holds ABC1, ABC2
```

Except works fine.

I suspect issue is in the item returned from the linq query.
Seems like f.BeerNames in first, and f in StoreList are not pointing to same datatype.

For heterogenous type

```
var list1 = from s in new String[] {"ABC1","ABC2", "ABC3", "ABC4"} select new {BeerName=s,Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}  ;
var list2 = new String[] {"ABC3","ABC4", "ABC5", "ABC6"} ;
var intermediateList = list1.Select(i=>i.BeerName).Except(list2);
var list3 = from l1 in list1
        join l2 in intermediateList on l1.BeerName equals l2
        select l1;


list1.Dump(); // run in linqPad
intermediateList.Dump();// run in linqPad
list3.Dump();// run in linqPad
```

list3 returns following

BeerName Id

ABC1 569ace9a-66c4-46aa-bbf5-50d586a2886f

ABC2 af456094-9692-4771-b489-8b3cca8aa938

Use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to run the above, or remove .Dump() to execute in VS.

Comment: Tilak, I don't think I can compare list1 to List2 because list2 is a List of Stores. I've tried List2.Select(x=>x.BeerName).Except(List1), but this returns data from List2.

Comment: list1,list2, list3 are just examples. 

You have 2 cases
1. you require only selected field (lets say BeerName). The selected field is same in both queries (ie x.BeerName is String, and List1 is list of string), then List2.Select(x=>x.BeerName).Except(List1) should work
2. If query results are hetrogenous, and you require all fields of list2 items, with condition, that BeerName should not exist in list 1, joins are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Except should work with the string type

```
var myList = MyFrig.Select(f => f.BeerNames).Except(Store).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Aducci. myList already has a valid list of Beers. What I want is a 3rd query that will compare myList to storeList, with the result a list of beers from myList that are not in storeList. MyFrig is a bad example, sorry. I'll change it.